# Como obter o valor do input hidden dentro da controller utilizando FormCollection?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou tentando obter o valor de um input hidden dentro do Controller por FormCollection, porém o valor vem zerado. Para incrementar o valor, estou usando uma função JavaScript.

**HTML:**

```
  <form id="adicionarTituloManual" action="~/Movimento/AdicionarCodevedoresTit" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" id="qtd" name="qtd" value="" />
    </form>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function novo(i) 
   {
        var form, quant;

        var qtd = document.getElementById('qtd').value

        if (qtd == 0) {
            document.getElementById('qtd').value = i;
        }
        else{
            i =  parseInt(document.getElementById('qtd').value) + 1;
            document.getElementById('qtd').value = i;
        }
    }
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult AdicionarCodevedoresTit(FormCollection formCollection)
{
    if (Session["usuario"] == null)
    {
        return Redirect("~/Home/Index");
    }
    else
    {
        this.usuario = (STLoginUsuario)Session["usuario"];
    }
    int qtd = HUtils.ConverteEmInteiro(formCollection["dvQtd"]);
    return Redirect("~/Movimento/AdicionarCoDevedor");
}
```

Comment: A chave do FormCollection deveria ser `qtd` e não `dvQtd`. Certo?

Comment: Vc tem razão! Obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A chave do `FormCollection` deve ser o valor do atributo `name` do `input`.

O código do *controller* deveria ser algo como

```
public ActionResult AdicionarCodevedoresTit(FormCollection formCollection)
{
    if (Session["usuario"] == null)
    {
        return Redirect("~/Home/Index");
    }
    else
    {
        this.usuario = (STLoginUsuario)Session["usuario"];
    }

    int qtd = HUtils.ConverteEmInteiro(formCollection["qtd"]);

    return Redirect("~/Movimento/AdicionarCoDevedor");
}
```

Comment: caso eu tenha um input criado dinamicamente por javascript, como faço para pegar os valores no Controller?

Comment: Acho melhor abrir outra pergunta. É um assunto completamente diferente.

Comment: Aliás, não sei se você sabe, mas, se a resposta te ajudou, podes marcá-la como correta usando o **V** do lado esquerdo da mesma.

Comment: É eu tentei marcar, mas apareceu uma mensagem, pedindo para eu esperar 2 minutos! Obrigado por lembrar

Comment: Mas no caso da minha pergunta no comentário. A reposta é : Da mesma forma!

Comment: E como você vai saber do lado do servidor quantos campos foram criados via JS?